# Vue watch on v-model property only fired once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, watch, v-model

I have a Vue component very similar to the example reported [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers):

```
watch: {
    query(n, o) {

        // Display loading animation
        this.loading = true;

        // Search debounced
        this.debouncedSearchUser();
    }
},
```

Where `query` is a String variable bound to a text input using `v-model`:

```
data() {

    return {
        query: "",
        loading: false,
        results: []
    }
},
```

Everything works fine, except on chrome for android where the watch trigger is only fired once (when `query` changes from `""` to whatever I write).

Any idea?

EDIT:

The problem seems to be related with the `v-model` directive: I made some experiments with native javascript events and the value of v-model is not updated until I unfocus the input. If anyone's interested here is the binding:

```
<input v-model="query" class="input-text-light pad-s-m f-m"/>
```

Any way to get around this using watch and `v-model`?

Comment: It works on the chrome desktop version?

Comment: Yes, on desktop it works perfectly. Anyway, I made some experiments (using native events such as 'keydown') and the problem is not the watch trigger but the `v-model` directive not updating `query` value. I'm updating the question

Comment: The most recent update to Chrome desktop is now in the same boat as the Android version. Unfortunate this happened. I'll have to abandon the v-model if I want to watch that property :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be a bug for `v-model`. Since `v-model` is just a syntactic sugar.
I think you can use the code below to make it work.

```
<input v-bind:value="query" v-on:input="query = $event.target.value"></input>
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this today and they actually call it a feature. See:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8723
There's more similar reports about this.